# Transform Future[A] to F[A] with Async[F]

Tags: scala, monads, future, scala-cats, tagless-final

I'm working with Slick and Cats.

`database.run` returns a `Future`, but I need the method of my class (generic on `F[_]: Async`) to return a monad `F`. I can make it work like this

```
val future = database.run(insertion)    
val result = Await.result(future, Duration.Inf)    
Async[F].delay(result)
```

but that is not the way it should be done for sure, since it's blocking the thread.

Is there any proper way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Async.fromFuture` is what you need.
As always, the [**scaladoc**](https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/api/cats/effect/Async$.html#fromFuture[F[_],A](fa:F[scala.concurrent.Future[A]])(implicitF:cats.effect.Async[F],implicitcs:cats.effect.ContextShift[F]):F[A]) is yout friend.

```
import cats.effect.{Async, ContextShift]

def foo[F[_] : Async : ContextShift]: F[Result] =
  Async.fromFuture(Async[F].delay(database.run(insertion)))
```